# TSC missing from available clocksources

Tags: linux, centos6, kernel, clock-synchronization

Not sure why `TSC` as a clock source is not available?

```
cat /sys/devices/system/clocksource/clocksource0/available_clocksource 
hpet acpi_pm
```

The CPU I'm using is `Intel Xeon(R) X5570  @ 2.93GHz`. The motherboard is `Supermicro X8DTU-F`. Running `CentOS 6.3 2.6.32-279.22.1.el6.x86_64`.

Not happy with the performance of `hpet` or `acpi_pm` measured using the following program.

```
#include <time.h>
main()
{
    int rc;
    long i;
    struct timespec ts;

    for(i=0; i<10000000; i++) {
        rc = clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &ts);
    }
}
```

With `hpet` as the clock source

```
time ./clock_timing
real    6m25.761s
user    6m23.456s
sys     0m0.403s
```

With `acpi_pm` as the clock source

```
time ./clock_timing
real    10m12.057s
user    0m6.615s
sys     10m2.549s
```

**Update**

`cat /proc/cmdline`

ro root=UUID=72903706-30bf-4285-9016-d24cf2066d3c rd_NO_LUKS rd_NO_LVM LANG=en_US.UTF-8 rd_NO_MD SYSFONT=latarcyrheb-sun16 crashkernel=132M@0M KEYBOARDTYPE=pc KEYTABLE=us rd_NO_DM vga=788 consoleblank=0 clocksource_failover=acpi_pm

`grep flags /proc/cpuinfo`

flags           : fpu vme de pse `tsc` msr pae mce cx8 apic mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx rdtscp lm `constant_tsc` arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf pni dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm dca sse4_1 sse4_2 popcnt lahf_lm ida dts tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid

Comment: Check your kernel command line.

Comment: grep tsc /proc/cpuinfo can help  you

Comment: hi guys, I updated the question with the outputs. I don't see anything unusual in `/proc/cmdline` and the CPU does TSC.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some pre-Westmere Intel CPU have a somewhat flawed TSC capability, maybe this is your case and the kernel is blacklisting the TSC as a timer source. Issue the following command

`dmesg | grep -i tsc`

and report here the output.

Comment: hi, good point! I did see some references in `/var/log/messages` that the kernel has switched to using `hpet` because of the unstableness of *tsc*. I guess I may have to change the CPUs to see if the problem goes away. I'l mark your answer as accepted once I confirm that is the case. Thanks.